# Redis Host Name Hosted on Google Compute Engine

Tags: redis, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Currently using the Google's Compute Engine to host Redis. Using the following [guide](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-redis-on-appengine?authuser=1), however, I'm unable to locate the Redis host name as I receive the following error within the logs:

```
Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

This is was the inside of my **keys.json** looks like:

```
{
   "redisHost" : "localhost",
   "redisPort": "6379",
   "redisKey": "bitnami_base_password"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply SSH'ed into my VM and used `hostname` command to retrieve the hostname used on GCP